# How to dynamically name and date a file for import?

Tags: import, files-and-directories

I want to import a data file named "A(var1)B(var2)C(var3).dat"
where the values of the variables var1, var2, var3 are being provided by a function. How can I do that?

Comment: Take a look at `StringJoin`, `ToString` or at `StringTemplate`.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 2;
b = 4;
c = 5;
StringJoin[ToString[a], ToString[b], ToString[c], ".dat"]
```

> "245.dat"

or you can add more strings

```
StringJoin["A",ToString[a],"_B",ToString[b],"_C",ToString[c], ".dat"]
```

> "A2_B4_C5.dat"